# Replicate path curve illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool

Is there a way to replicate the curve of one side of the path to the other? I want to make it symmetrical or do I use smart guides somehow to snap it to the same curve as the other side?

[image]

Comment: Is it impossible to split with the scissors the not so symmetric path in the middle, duplicate and reflect the better half to get a mirror image, place it and join?

Comment: Yes I did consider cutting the path and I do do that sometimes but I was just wondering if there was a quicker way almost like a copy and paste option

Comment: @user3413128 Sure just record it as an action and then it as quick as pushing a button/keyboard shortcut? Is that what your after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator often has many different ways to achieve something. Here's one way:

1. Draw one half the symmetric shape you want to create:

[image: draw half of the shape]

2. In the **Appearance Panel** (Windows/Appearance) apply a **Transform-Effect** (fx/Distort & Transform/Transform):

[image: Transform the shape]

Here you need to check the **Reflect X** option, enter the number of **copies** (in this case 1) and choose the bottom left corner as the **object origin**.

Now the half shape you have drawn will be mirrored to the left. Any changes to the original half of the shape will automatically apply to the mirrored side as well:

[image: the modified shape]

**Expand the Appearance** of the object if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. draw one half of your shape, preferably using a vertical guide to ensure you stop drawing at the intended vertical axis;
2. select the entire shape using the move tool;
3. switch to the Reflect tool (in the same group as Rotate, shortkey <kbd>O</kbd>);
4. hold your left <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd> key and hover until your Smart Guides tell you you are right on top of an anchor that sits on the intended axis;
5. still holding <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd>, <kbd>click</kbd>;
6. in the dialog box, choose a vertical axis and rather than clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>, choose <kbd>Copy</kbd>.